# Autodesk Forge - Document Management "Description" and "Sets" information availability

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Is there a way to retrieve the "Description" and "Sets" information for a specific item version in BIM360 Document Management?

[image: BIM360 File fields]

I couldn't find any of them in the current Forge available endpoints for neither BIM360 or Data Management APIs:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-GET/
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-GET/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hate to disappoint you, but it is true no API yet for the Description or Sets yet. We have two wishes tickets:

- FDM-3124: wish: expose [Description] with GET :Folder Contents
- ALEX-24690: [Public API] Expose BIM 360 SET via DM API

I have appended your requests to the two tickets. You patience and understanding are appreciated.